# How do I combine a list of ranges in Python?

Tags: python

For example, I have a list like this:

```
list_of_ranges = [range(0,5),range(10,100),range(500,777),range(1337,9001)]
```

My goal is to have a flattened list that combines all of the range functions. So it should look like this in the end:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,10,11,12,...,8999,9000]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `itertools.chain` and unpack your list using the `*` character to make this work. Just do:

```
from itertools import chain
list_of_ranges = [range(0,5),range(10,100),range(500,777),range(1337,9001)]
list(chain(*list_of_ranges))
```

Output:

```
[0,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 10,
 11,
 12,
 13,
 14,
...
```

You can read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: The `*` operator does _not_ dereference. [It unpacks the list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: Thx, I edited it to include the link. I had a hard time finding answers to this because it was not a list of lists, but a list of ranges, and ranges aren't lists...But it turns out the solution is exactly the same